# Can one run postgres SQL queries in SSMS 19 (Preview)

Tags: postgresql, ssms, azure-data-studio, ssms-19

In Azure Data Studio one can download extension of multiple SQL clients and run SQL Queries, but wanted to check if in latest version of SSMS if we can do same things. Reason being one has to deal with multiple clients for running queries across multiple databases.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16][1]

Comment: SSMS only works with Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Are you confusing SSMS with Azure Data Studio? ADS supports PostgreSQL for a couple of years now. You can also use VS Code with a PostgreSQL extension. ADS is essentially a VS Code shell with SQL Server (and now PostgreSQL) extensions

Comment: Funny. It doesn't make sense not to have extensions in SSMS.

Comment: Add-ins for SSMS do exist, @PKernel ; just many you need to pay for. It's built on a completely different underlying application. ADS is a reshelled VSCode, which is an electron app. SSMS is a Visual Studio Shell, and was written in C++.